# Statistics for neurological health vs. death

Tags: brain, statistics, death

Friends and I have been discussing mental health and lifespan due to examples of family members with dementia who could live for another 15-20 years vs. family members whose minds were sharp as a tack and lived past 100.

My question is this: are there studies that provide insight into how often the "brain breaks" before the death of the body? Said another way, how likely is the brain to suffer degradation before the body dies?

Comment: A crude measure might be to look at deaths where Alzheimers is listed as a contributing cause (not that all mental degradation is AD, of course). There is some difficulty in defining what it means for "the brain to suffer degradation before the body dies", as everyone's brain is degrading in some sense from the time they are a young adult. Apart from traumatic injury, no one is going to go from "not degraded" to "degraded" overnight, so it's a difficult thing to binarize. People tend to still have quite a bit of valuable life left after they're already showing clear signs of decline.

Comment: Then perhaps also consider the [Relation between IQ and age](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Relationship-between-IQ-at-age-11-in-the-Scottish-Mental-Survey-1932-and-survival-to-age_fig3_289963900) and the comparison between [Fluid and Crystalized Intelligence](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/TwjKr4KayRm4JvoXi/age-fluid-intelligence-and-intelligent-posts) over the years.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.